# Prestashop: how to recognize admin password, having FTP and MySql parameters?

Tags: authentication, passwords, admin, prestashop

I have only FTP and MySql access parameters. My client didn't tell me the password to access the dashboard. How could I recovery it?
(I haven't email access, so I can't use the normal recovery and I can't contact my client before next 2 day...)

Comment: Contacting the vendor may be more appropriate for questions regarding access credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the password hash of one of your customer (or create a new one) from ps_customers table to the password field of employee in ps_employee table.

PS: pub@prestashop.com customer is created by default, if still exists use that password hash. (Password for this customer is 123456789).

Answer (score 1):

Use any free online MD5 generator like http://www.md5hashgenerator.com
but ecode COOKIE_KEY from settings.inc.php and new Password (with no space).

'COOKIE_KEYNewPassword' example 'bWZbVe5OEq4nwbWZbVe5OEq4nwbVe5OEq4nwnJI2xj8g3nAW1GC1y5KTwMyPassword’

Now cope your new password (MyPassword) to the ps_employee table in your  database instead of the old pass.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting admin password through phpmyadmin on prestashop 8

- Get cookie_key from app/config/parameters.php.
- Then go to prestashop database and find table "ps_employee".
- Click on edit button on the row that you need to reset password.
- Clear the password field and paste the cookie_key and your password. (Eg. If your cookie_key is "qwerty" and password is "12345", then it should be qwerty12345)
- Then choose "MD5" on function column and press go.
- Now you can login with email and updated password.

Answer (score -1):

In your database go and look at the table named PS_employee

While there add a new line with appropriate info and for password use this generator

http://www.md5hashgenerator.com

BR's

(don't forget to accept when this answer helps you )

Comment: The answer is wrong. The password in PrestaShop is not MD5 encrypted.

Comment: Yes it is. Just by default prestashop adds cookie_key to it. Im not sure if this might interrupt with the whole process or not.

Comment: The answer is completely wrong. The PrestaShop password is being generated by concatenation of the _COOKIE_KEY_ constant from config/settings.inc.php and the password, and over that key the md5 function is applied. It is not added "by default", but explicitly. If the user have MySQL access, he does not need 3rd party sites to generate the hash - this can be done with the mysql function md5().